# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/andrey/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker

docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/$USER/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.

sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl start docker

Comment: Solved 


Juste remove the folder: .docker at home 

sudo rm -rf /home/$USER/.docker


helped me on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a recommendation, try making your questions more verbose as to indicate your OS, the software version you're working with, the steps to reproduce it and some solutions tryed. Writing a good question will improve your chances of getting the right answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**I had same problem**

It is a context problem that originates when we use docker engine and docker desktop.

They can be installed on the same PC without problem but using different contexts for each one.

to see these contexts we use

```
docker context ls
```

in your case it will show you selected docker desktop context with an asterisk

```
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                    KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR                      
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                                                                
desktop-linux *     moby                                                          unix:///home/gregory/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

to change it we use

```
docker context use
```

which for docker engine should be default

```
docker context use default
```

and with this you shouldn't have any problems

or at least this worked for me

**reference** [Frequently asked questions for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#what-is-the-difference-between-docker-desktop-for-linux-and-docker-engine)